# Android Native Library Crash on accessing Function that returns empty std::string

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am building an android native library i.e .so file using ndk-build and using it in my cocos2dx project. When I access any of the method of the library that returns empty string, it crashes straight away on OS higher than 5.0 only. Below is my Application.mk file, I have tried of add different options but no avail.

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -std=c++11 -fsigned-char -fexceptions
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

If I return anything else than empty string like "0", it works fine. But on just accessing the method that return empty string, is a straight crash. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use only `armeabi ` or I would write `APP_ABI := arm64-v8a x86 armeabi armeabi-v7a`

Comment: Compile in debug mode, grab a stacktrace from when the code crashes, and add it to your question. Also add the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: I have no idea how but I am able to solve the issue. Here is how to able to return empty string.

string value("0");
value.clear();
return value;

Comment: actually I am using APP_ABI := all. armeabi is replaced for quick compilation.